# Angular JS for Mutually Exclusive Selections

Tags: angularjs

I have two selection tag, each with the same options. The behavior that I am aiming for is to have whatever the selected option of one not be selectable on the options of the other one. Given that I am using an array of objects for the source of the options: [{name:'one'}, {name:'two'}, {name:'three'}]

**1. Default.**

selection 1
- one
- two
- three

selection 2
- one
- two
- three

**2. Selection 1 gets selected.**

selection 1
- one
- two
-(three)

selection 2
- one
- two

**3. Selection 2 gets selected.**

selection 1
- two
-(three)

selection 2
-(one)
- two

Answer (score 4):

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Quadraxas/9nsTd/6/)

You can do this by using a custom filter function to filter out already selected options.

```
<select ng-model="picks.select1">
     <option ng-repeat="option in options | filter:optionFilter(picks.select1)" ng-value="option.name">
```

This function takes the model of the select as the parameter to be able to show it as still selectable.

```
 $scope.optionFilter = function(selectedOptionModel){
    return function(option){
       //actual filtering function starts here, angular passes all items in the array
       // to this function and filters out the ones you returned false

       if(option.name === selectedOptionModel) return true;  // if it's already the selected option it should still be an option in the dropdown
        else{
            for(var key in $scope.picks){
                //otherwise we check to see if they are picked in 
                //another select dropdown and immediately return false because
                // that option is elected should be filtered out.
                if(option.name===$scope.picks[key]) return false;
            }
            //if we successfully got out of the loop it means it's not selected so return true
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```